# Windows 8: programmatically preventing start window

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, desktop

I'm developing classroom control software. One of the features is that the teacher must be able to prevent the user from seeing the start screen. The application running on the student side is running in the windows 8 desktop. How can I, from C++ code, prevent the user from going to the start screen? If that is not possible I can maybe force the application to switch back to the desktop view at certain times. Can this be achieved from code?

Comment: Are you talking about a kiosk mode for your application?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a complex topic, I won't duplicate the content here. Creating a kiosk style application hinges around Authenticode signed executables and the UIAccess manifest property. You should also understand the [Certification requirements for Windows 8 desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh749939.aspx) because kiosk style applications can be a large security risk if not properly designed.

1. [Kiosk style application in Windows 8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/5eb76d8d-5c47-48a4-ad7b-f052c95df3ef)
2. [Desktop apps on top of Metro](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/8529357f-3ff8-4c83-baaf-5215ca9cc14a)
3. [Using the uiAccess attribute of requestedExecutionLevel to Improve Applications Providing Remote Control of the Desktop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/10/15/using-the-uiaccess-attribute-of-requestedexecutionlevel-to-improve-applications-providing-remote-control-of-the-desktop.aspx)
4. [Step 6: Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)